# Get a resource item by string winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, resources

In a C# Winforms app, how can I access `Resources` via string? For example I know I can do `Properties.Resources.MyImage` however, I won't know which image I need until runtime. With a string containing `"MyImage"`, how can I access `Properties.Resources.MyImage`? Ideally, I was hoping for something easy such as `Properties.Resources["MyImage"]`, but with some searching around haven't been able to find a quick solution to this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Get an object from resources and typecast that to a bitmap `Bitmap myImage = (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("myImage");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ResourceManager.GetObject()` like this:

```
string resourceName = "MyImageNameHere";
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(resourceName);
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```