# Windows Forms Image Resource

Tags: c#, windows, forms, random, properties

Im making a Random Generator with Windows Forms with Images and I use the random pick with resources `pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.heart;`
Now, the "heart" should get removed from the List, to prevent getting "heart" again.
Here I thought, that I just use `int firstCard = randomCard.Next(cards.Count);` and I want to use the `int firstCard` as `Properties.Resources.cards[firstCard]`, because behind `Properties.Resources.` comes the resource name. But the string doesnt work there, and I dont know how to fix that. Pls help.

Thank you
Pults

Answer (score 1):

Oh yeah, someone asked the same, didnt find it.
Yea the "ResourceManager.GetObject" is exactly what I needed.

Thanks for the quick response and instant solve!

Answer (score 0):

Add all your images to a `List<Image>` - if you have 100 images your list will end up with 100 things

Pick one at random and also remove it. Make the upper bound of random the number of things in the list

```
//do this once outside the loop that adds images: var r = new Random();
```

Then the loop that adds images

```
var x = r.Next(imageList.Count);

var i = inageList[x]; //get the image 
imageList.RemoveAt(x); //can't get it again
```

---

Note that setting the image of a picture box cannot be done in addition; you'll need multiple picture boxes

---

Side note, you might find it easier to keep your images in an ImageList (easier to index numerically) - the [documentation for it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imagelist?view=net-5.0) also has some useful/helpful example codes that iteratively draws images into a PictureBox

Also, [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44104335/get-a-resource-item-by-string-winforms) (maybe doing the same exercise as you :) ) wondered how to get images by string name..